# How do I make the text of one label node take up 2 lines?

Tags: xcode, string, swift, text, sklabelnode

I have this text below that is too long to fit on the screen when it runs. How can I make this 2 lines rather than one?

```
myLabel.text = "The weather today is going to be partly cloudy with a chance of rain"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit/update:

**For iOS 11 or later you can set [numberOfLines](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sklabelnode/2865815-numberoflines), [lineBreakMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sklabelnode/2865818-linebreakmode), and [preferredMaxLayoutWidth](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sklabelnode/2865814-preferredmaxlayoutwidth) properties. [attributedText](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sklabelnode/2865817-init) is supported as well **

Original answer

---

You can create your own method to display multi line text as follow:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        displayMultiLineTextAt(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - 100, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 50, align: SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.Left, lineHeight: 20.0, text: "Welcome to StackOverFlow!\nThe weather today is going to\nbe partly cloudy with a chance\nof rain.")
    }
    func displayMultiLineTextAt(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, align: SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode, lineHeight: CGFloat, text: String) {
        let textNode = SKNode()
        textNode.position = CGPointMake(x, y)
        var lineAt: CGFloat = 0
        for line in text.componentsSeparatedByString("\n") {
            let labelNode = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Arial")
            labelNode.fontSize = 14
            labelNode.horizontalAlignmentMode = align
            labelNode.fontColor = SKColor(hue: 1, saturation: 1, brightness: 1, alpha: 1)
            labelNode.position = CGPointMake(0, lineAt)
            labelNode.text = line
            textNode.addChild(labelNode)
            lineAt -= lineHeight
        }
        scene!.addChild(textNode)
    }
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */
    }
    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**#1**
Set the number of lines:

```
myLabel.numberOfLines = 2 //set to 0 if you want it to automatically decide based on how many line breaks you add in step 2
```

**#2**
Add line breaks in your text using `\n` or `\r`:

```
myLabel.text = "The weather today is going to\nbe partly cloudy with a chance of rain"
```

Hope that helps :)

**Edit**

You should have clarified that you are using a `SKLabelNode` rather than a normal `UILabel`. Here is what you could do since `SKLabelNode`s do not support multiple lines.

- create a new view
- add label #1 to the view
- add another label (#2) to the view, place it below label #1
- split the sentence into two parts, add first part to label #1 and second to label #2

Comment: Thanks for the response. For some reason it won't let me do numberOfLines. It is giving the error "SKLabelNode does not have a member numberOfLines"

Comment: Oh ok well with `SKLabelNode`s it appears not to be possible. What you could do is to create a view and add your current and another one to it. Put half the text in label 1 and the other half in label 2. Place label 2 maybe ~10 below label 1. That will seem like 2 lines.

Answer (score -2):

- `myLabel.numberOfLines = 2` //or set to 0
- make sure `myLabel.frame.size.height` is enough

Comment: Thanks for the response. For some reason it won't let me do numberOfLines. It is giving the error "SKLabelNode does not have a member numberOfLines"

Comment: SKLabelNode definitely doesn't support this. It is different from normal textLabel. You have to write some code to enable it to show two lines.